# SMTP Sampler executes receives IOExeception while sending message

Tags: performance, smtp, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I'm using jmeter 3.2, I want run a SMTP Sampler in Jmeter where I have done the necessary configuration by adding the javamail file in the lib folder of Jmeter and adding necessary credentials in the mail setting, though when executed I am getting an error of IOException.

Am I missing any step?

[image: IOExecption]

Comment: put the file in bin directory and try again.

Comment: @Jahan : thank,i got it but there is one issue where it displays an IO Expection error in the response message. Screenshot is also attached

Comment: Do you use jmeter 3.2? if so there maybe a bug see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188612/jmeter-3-2-smtp-smapler-failed , check if Jmeter 3.1 reproduce the issue

Comment: @user7294900 : yes i m currently using this version. sure i will recheck this with 3.1 and provide an update on it

Answer (score 2):

There was a change in [SMTP Sampler](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/259) in jmeter 3.2 which created several [bugs](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61285).

You open a bug to [jmeter](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=JMeter) with a sample if it's a different scenario.

If you can downgrade to Jmeter 3.1 if it can work.

**EDIT**

You can download a fix to the issue in [jmeter-3.3](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send a file as an attachment you have 2 options:

1. If you are using relative path (just filename) make sure you put the file into JMeter's "bin" folder. So JMeter could find it. Check out *jmeter.log* file to know where JMeter is expecting the file to be.

   [image: JMeter SMTP Log file]
2. Use full path (like `c:\somefolder\someotherfolder\somefile.eml`)

In case if you still experience the problem update your question with your email server configuration and *jmeter.log* file contents. In the meantime check out [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article

Comment: Thanks I have gone through the article and verified the same in my example for the issue i have updated the same above.