# jmeter 3.2 Smtp smapler failed

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

[image: request]
[image: response]

The same script works in jmeter 3.1 but not in jmeter 3.2, why?

Can someone answer that?

**EDIT 1:**

Open [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61319) for jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a change in [SMTP Sampler](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/pull/259) in jmeter 3.2

Which wasn't tested. I suggest you open a bug to [jmeter](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=JMeter) with a sample.

If you can't post bug I can post it for you if you give sample jmx that doesn't work.

If you can downgrade to Jmeter 3.1 it can work.

> I understand this is a fairly big change with no tests but I thought
>   I'd submit anyway in the hope that someone had some good SMTP tests or
>   someone was willing to review or even just apply a subset of the
>   changes.

There's also existing [bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61285) reported on SMTP Smapler in Jmeter 3.2.

**EDIT**

You can download a fix to the issue in [jmeter-3.3](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

Comment: Thank you for your answer。I have submitted questions in bz.apache.org/bugzilla

Comment: Can you share a link to your question in stackoverflow? also there's 1 bug for SMTP https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61285

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in Jmeter 3.2.

I got the report stored in a file and gave the path to that file "Attach file(s)" section and its sending email successfully.

Comment: i enable extent reporting and point the path to the location where the file has been generated.

/Users/rohithpolusani/Desktop/Screen Shot 2018-08-23 at 3.37.06 PM.png